# Instance of OracleConnection does not work in Webservice

Tags: web-services, oracle

I am working on a webservice which connects to a OracleDatabase. 
I already implemented this service as asp.net Service, but now got to transform this as a Sharepoint Solution to use the Sharepoint deployment mechanisms.

at the following line an Exception is thrown ( Registry access is not allowed )

```
var conn = new Sytem.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection()
```

also changing this to ODP.net does not work ( have to attach the dll in the Package Advanced feature ), but then a ORA-12545 comes up:

```
var conn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection()
```

But - if the code is used in a WebPart, aspx - Page it works like a charm on the same SiteCollection as the webservice - also no ORA-12545 failure
Is there some trust configuration that OracleConnections cannot be instanced??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the problem - The lookup from Hostaddress defined in the connectionstring did not work. Now i am using the IP of the Oracle-Server and everything is working now.